# Combining date and time variable in Stata

Tags: date, datetime, stata

I am trying to combine a date and time variable into a date/time variable in Stata.

Suppose `date = 23jun2015` and `time = 31dec1899 11:23:00` and suppose that I want to create a new variable `datetime= 23jun2015 11:23:00`.

The format of `date` is `%tdNN/DD/CCYY` and the format of `time` is `%tcHH:MM:SS`

I have tried the following code

```
gen double datetime = date*24*60*60*1000 + time
format datetime %tcNN/DD/CCYY_HH:MM:SS
```

However, somehow I get the following result (the year is wrong):

```
23jun1955 11:23:00
```

Any ideas how I can change this to get the correct year?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should point you in the right direction.

```
clear
set obs 1
generate date = daily("23jun2015","DMY")
generate double time = clock("31dec1899 11:23:00","DMY hms")
format date %tdNN/DD/CCYY
format time %tcHH:MM:SS

generate double datetime = dhms(date,hh(time),mm(time),ss(time))
format datetime %tcNN/DD/CCYY_HH:MM:SS

list
```

If you have not already done so, you will want to review `help datetime`, which is without a doubt the most visited documentation on my system, with the second-most-visited being Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the *Stata User's Guide* PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 thoroughly. After that, the help datetime documentation will usually be enough to point the way. Some people may be able to remember everything without have to continually refer to the documentation, but I for one am not such a person.